# WordPress excerpt character count not working

Tags: wordpress

My loop looks like this:

```
<!-- loop for the posts here -->
<?php
    $args = array(
        'post_type' => 'post',
        'posts_per_page' => 3,
        'category_name' => 'news'
    );
    $query = new WP_Query($args);
    while($query->have_posts()) : $query->the_post();
?>  
    <div class="news_box_content">
        <h5><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h5>
        <figure><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_post_thumbnail(); ?></a></figure>
        <?php if($post->post_excerpt) { ?>
            <p><?php echo get_the_excerpt(); ?></p>
            <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">Read more...</a>
        <?php } else {
            the_content('Read More');
        } ?>
    </div>
<?php endwhile; wp_reset_postdata(); ?>
```

I used a function to count the excerpt length but it is not working.

```
function custom_excerpt_length(){
   return 10;
}
add_filter('excerpt_length', 'custom_excerpt_length');
```

How can I limit the number of characters on any excerpt?

Comment: You need to call your custom excerpt function in your loop  i.e custom_excerpt_length();  instead of get_the_excerpt();

Comment: Oops..yes you are right.

Answer (score 0):

No need for an extra filter

```
echo substr(get_the_excerpt(), 0,10);
```

Comment: It works for the excerpt, but not the content.
this works: <?php echo substr(get_the_excerpt(), 0,300); ?>
But this does not work: echo substr(the_content('Read More'), 0,150);

Answer (score 0):

Try this one. I always use this one

```
<?php 
      $content = get_the_content();
      $content = strip_tags($content);

      $dots = strlen(substr($content,0,50)) < 50 ? " " : "...";
      echo substr($content,0,50) . $dots;
      ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your functions.php file:

```
function trim_excerpt( $exc ) {
    $exc_trimmed = substr( $exc, 0, 150 ) . '...';
    return $exc_trimmed;
}
add_filter( 'the_excerpt', 'trim_excerpt', 999 );
```